# INSERT INTO mysqli prepared statement error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have this query that gives me an error about the `mysqli_bind_param()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given

here is the query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $user_name, $pass, $first_name, $last_name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

this is the code for my connection:

```
<?php

$mysql_error = 'Could not connect';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_db = 'users';

$conn = @mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db) or die($mysql_error); 


?>
```

EDIT:

This is the database name: users
This is the table name: user
this is the column names:
`id`, `user_name`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`

Comment: An error on `mysqli_bind_param()` while I don't see the function in your code? Secondly that specific function requires a connection, in your case `$conn` as first argument. Also, suppressing error reporting with `@` and requesting help on it is a no-go. Infact, anything related in PHP that has `@` in it is asking for trouble.

Comment: have you tried to make checking the connection (success or not)?

Comment: yes it is working in my other query. only in my `INSERT` query is not working

Comment: `$stmt` is `false` indicating an error on prepare. ("expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given"). What is `mysqli_error(mysqli $conn)` after prepare?

Comment: what do you mean error after prepare?

Comment: `mysqli_error($conn)` after preparing the statement. You have any idea what you are doing?

Comment: it gives me this error `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice1\super_admin\create_success.php on line 10`

Comment: Not after bind - after prepare

Comment: but i use that to all of my query such as `UPDATE` `SELECT` it gives me error only in `INSERT INTO` statement only

Comment: Read the error  immediately after prepare.

Comment: im really sorry im confused right now

Comment: is it possible that the error is in my query?

Comment: Yes, e.g. table / column names.

Comment: i edited my post. i include all the information of my database

Comment: "This is the table name: **user**" / INSERT INTO **users** - Try ``INSERT INTO `users`.`user` ``